# CUDA - Extract Layer from 3D array

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda, gpu, gpgpu, pycuda

I have a 3D matrix where the x-y plane(s) represent an image and the z-plane represents image layers.
The issue is when I try to extract the first (or other layers) using idz, I do not get the expected results.  It looks like the array, once in CUDA, has different indexes for x, y or z than what I expect (as in pycuda).  I see this by the result array below.
The following is a step by step process for this mini example (I used generic int numbers to represent my images to save uploading images and the entire code)!

Here I import libraries and define image size and layers...

```
import pycuda.driver as cuda
import pycuda.autoinit
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule
import numpy
from pycuda.gpuarray import to_gpu

row = 10
column = 10
depth = 5
```

Then I define my input 3D array and my output 2D array...

```
#--==== Input 3D Array ====---
arrayA = numpy.full((row, column, depth), 0)

#populate each layer with fixed values
for i in range(depth):
    arrayA[:,:,i] = i + 1

arrayA = arrayA.astype(numpy.uint16)
arrayA_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(arrayA.nbytes)
cuda.memcpy_htod(arrayA_gpu, arrayA)
arrayA_Answer = numpy.empty_like(arrayA)

#--==== Output 2D array container ====---
arrayB = numpy.zeros([row, column], dtype = numpy.uint16)
arrayB_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(arrayB.nbytes)
cuda.memcpy_htod(arrayB_gpu, arrayB)
arrayB_Answer = numpy.empty_like(arrayB)
```

Next I define the CUDA kernal and function in pycuda

```
mod = SourceModule("""
    __global__ void getLayer(int *arrayA, int *arrayB)
    {
        int idx = threadIdx.x + (blockIdx.x * blockDim.x); // x coordinate (numpy axis 2) 
        int idy = threadIdx.y + (blockIdx.y * blockDim.y); // y coordinate (numpy axis 1)
        int idz = 0; //The first layer, this can set in range from 0-4 
        int x_width = (blockDim.x * gridDim.x); 
        int y_width = (blockDim.y * gridDim.y); 

        arrayB[idx + (x_width * idy)] = arrayA[idx + (x_width * idy) + (x_width * y_width) * idz];
    }
    """)

func = mod.get_function("getLayer")
func(arrayA_gpu, arrayB_gpu, block=(row, column, 1), grid=(1,1))
```

Using standard pycuda commands, I extract the results (not what I expected) 
arrayA[:,:,0] = 10x10 matrix populated with 1's (good)

```
print(arrayA_Answer[:,:,0])
[[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]]
```

arrayB[:,:]   = 10x10 matrix populated with the following (bad), expected to be equal to arrayA[:,:,0]...

```
print(arrayB_Answer)
[[1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5]
 [1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5]
 [1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5]
 [1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5]
 [1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5]
 [1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5]
 [1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5]
 [1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5]
 [1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5]
 [1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5]]
```

Comment: Hi Robert Crovella, thanks for the prompt response.  As I suspected, and as you helped out, it was a re-ordering issues.  Updated my program with the details below and got it working.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32127536/inplace-transpose-of-3d-array-in-pycuda), the numpy 3D storage order pattern is that the "`z`" (i.e. "3rd") index is the rapidly varying index, as you progress linearly through memory.  Your code assumes that the first index ("`x`") is the rapidly varying one.

Since your kernel is already organized for efficient ("coalesced") load/store behavior, you could address this by reordering the storage of your images/layers/slices in numpy.  Here is a worked example:

```
$ cat t10.py
from __future__ import print_function
import pycuda.driver as cuda
import pycuda.autoinit
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule
import numpy
from pycuda.gpuarray import to_gpu

row = 5
column = 10
depth = 10

#--==== Input 3D Array ====---
arrayA = numpy.full((row, column, depth), 0)
my_slice=numpy.int32(3)  # choose the layer
#populate each layer with fixed values
for i in range(row):
    arrayA[i,:,:] = i + 1

arrayA = arrayA.astype(numpy.int32)
arrayA_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(arrayA.nbytes)
cuda.memcpy_htod(arrayA_gpu, arrayA)
arrayA_Answer = numpy.empty_like(arrayA)

#--==== Output 2D array container ====---
arrayB = numpy.zeros([column, depth], dtype = numpy.int32)
arrayB_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(arrayB.nbytes)
cuda.memcpy_htod(arrayB_gpu, arrayB)
arrayB_Answer = numpy.empty_like(arrayB)

mod = SourceModule("""
    __global__ void getLayer(int *arrayA, int *arrayB, int slice)
    {
        int idx = threadIdx.x + (blockIdx.x * blockDim.x); // x coordinate (numpy axis 2)
        int idy = threadIdx.y + (blockIdx.y * blockDim.y); // y coordinate (numpy axis 1)
        int idz = slice; //The "layer"
        int x_width = (blockDim.x * gridDim.x);
        int y_width = (blockDim.y * gridDim.y);

        arrayB[idx + (x_width * idy)] = arrayA[idx + (x_width * idy) + (x_width * y_width) * idz];
    }
    """)

func = mod.get_function("getLayer")
func(arrayA_gpu, arrayB_gpu, my_slice, block=(depth, column, 1), grid=(1,1))
cuda.memcpy_dtoh(arrayB_Answer,arrayB_gpu)

print(arrayA[my_slice,:,:])

print(arrayB_Answer[:,:])
$ python t10.py
[[4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4]
 [4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4]
 [4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4]
 [4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4]
 [4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4]
 [4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4]
 [4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4]
 [4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4]
 [4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4]
 [4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4]]
[[4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4]
 [4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4]
 [4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4]
 [4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4]
 [4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4]
 [4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4]
 [4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4]
 [4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4]
 [4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4]
 [4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4]]
$
```

Note that I have also changed your use of `uint16` to `int32`, to match the kernel type `int`.